# Reduction of an adverb clause - Acceptable?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

> One study shows babies can learn **before they are born**. (ORIGINAL VERSION)
>
> One study shows babies can learn **before having born**. (VERSION I AM TALKING ABOUT)

Can I reduce this adverb clause like the way I used above?

Answer (score 1):

No, the verb **to bear** always has the baby as its object (the mother is the subject), so you can't grammatically say "a baby having born."

**To bear** in the sense of "to give birth to" is kind of a weird verb in that modern usage almost exclusively uses the passive voice (see the Usage Note about halfway down the page of the [definition of bear](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bear)).  To use the passive voice you must have a conjugated form of the verb **to be** followed by the past participle of **to bear**, which is **born**.

In the simple present: "The baby is born," or "...they are born," as in your example.

You're trying to use the past perfect, with the auxiliary verb "have" turned into a gerund so that it can serve as the object of the preposition "before."  To do that, you still need to include a form of **to be**:

> One study shows babies can learn before **having been born**.

This preserves the passive voice by using the past participle of **to be**, which is **been**.

In a less artificial exercise, if you want to make the sentence more concise, you could drop the verbal phrase altogether and just use the noun **birth** (although that's not what I think you mean by a "reduction" of the adverb clause).

> One study shows babies can learn before **birth**.